# Using The va_list to generate a string

Tags: c++

Im using c++ to create a custom monitor using the lvgl library. So ive saw that the "..." can handle infinite variables. I wanted to create a function to convert the string and the following parameters into a pure string. I want the function to take in a character pointer, then the "...". I want it to take out the "%d" parts of the character pointer and replace it with the corresponding value in the va_list. If the va_list is empty, it can return the same character pointer. How can I achieve this? i have no knowledge about the "...", i only know they are called varidic functions.

Thanks all for your kind help!

Comment: As C++, have you considered using variadic templates instead?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt